# Добавить перед уже сформированным числом 3 новых числа

Tags: oracle, plsql, plsql-developer

Нужно добавить число `188`, перед уже сформированным числом, например есть число `110 0000 000`.
И мне по заданию надо чтобы было `188 110 0000 000`.
Самое числовое значение `varchar`,и я подумал что может стоить так.

```
update myTable1 myTbl
 set myTbl.NMBCODE='188'+myTbl.NMBCODE       --- вставляем символы числа перед основной строковой переменной(оба значения varchar),конкатенация..
```

Но данный способ не правильный так как на `+myTbl.TNMBCODE` вылетает ошибка `ORA01722-Invalid Number`

Скажите пожалуйста, какие существуют механизмы решения данной проблемы.

Comment: `... set myTbl.NMBCODE = '188' || myTbl.NMBCODE`. Число будет неявно преобразовано в строку, сконкатенировано, потом преобразовано обратно. Но если число отрицательное - получится, само собой, ошибка преобразования (`ORA-01722: invalid number`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
update myTable1 myTbl
set myTbl.NMBCODE = '188' || myTbl.NMBCODE
-- where myTbl.NMBCODE >= 0
```